# Underscore/Lodash vs. From Scratch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

I'm a student and recently got into using Underscore and/or Lodash, and as English is my second language, I sometimes have a hard time understanding what exactly some of these Underscore/Lodash functions are doing.

I'm particularly interested in how to solve this scenario I am working with at the moment...suppose I have an array of objects that in turn contain an array of documents; if I wanted to identify if one of these document are of a certain type, and if it is, return the object that the document is associated with. So in my case, I'm working with an array of Invoice objects, that in turn has an array of documents, and to solve the scenario I used the following JavaScript code:

`let invoice = null;`

```
for(let i = 0; i < $scope.invoices.length; i++){
    let docs = $scope.invoices[i].documents;
    if(docs && docs.length){
       for(let j = 0; j < docs.length; j++) {
           if(docs[j].type === 'document_xxxx'){
                 invoice = $scope.invoices[i];
                 break;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to understand the easiest way of accomplishing the same thing, but using Underscore/Lodash. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (or their lodash equivalents - [*.find*](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) and [.some](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#some)).

On each iteration of Array#find, the invoice documents are iterated using Array#some, and if one of them has the correct type, Array#some returns `true`, and Array#find returns the invoice.

```js
const invoices = [{ id: 1, documents: [{ type: 'document_mmmm' }] }, { id: 2, documents: [{ type: 'document_xxx1' }, { type: 'document_xxxx' }, { type: 'document_xx3x' }] }, { id: 3, documents: [{ type: 'document_zzz' }] }];

const result = invoices.find(({ documents = [] }) => 
  documents.some((d) => d.type === 'document_xxxx'));

console.log(result);
```

Using underscore:

```js
const invoices = [{ id: 1, documents: [{ type: 'document_mmmm' }] }, { id: 2, documents: [{ type: 'document_xxx1' }, { type: 'document_xxxx' }, { type: 'document_xx3x' }] }, { id: 3, documents: [{ type: 'document_zzz' }] }];

const result = _.find(invoices, ({ documents = [] }) => 
  _.some(documents, (d) => d.type === 'document_xxxx'));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for clarifying this for me. Much appreciated. @ori-drori

Comment: Hey again @ori-drori, so I attempted to convert what you wrote to Underscore functions, but it is returning undefined at this point. Seeing anything I did incorrectly? 
`const result = _.find($scope.invoices, (documents) => {
                                _.some(documents, (doc) => {
                                    return doc.type === 'renewalInvoice';
                                });
                            });`

Comment: Welcome again :)